# How to find cos(X) sin(X) in a rotation when X is unknown

Tags: rotations

I'd like to perform rotation from one vector to the other. 
I have two formulaes to get sin(X) and cos(X), X being the rotation angle, but I can't see where they come from :

```
denom = a * a + b * b;
sin(X) = ( b * ta - a * tb ) / denom;
cos(X) = ( a * ta + b * tb ) / denom;
```

Can somebody help me to clear this out ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the formulas for getting the lengths of the sides of a right triangle?  The `denom` variable is a big hint.  The numerators are not familiar to me, but I'm guessing they are due to a transformation matrix.

Comment: @abiessu, sure, but why keep it to the square ? Numerators are what puzzle me the most...

Comment: I'm not certain on why it is still squared, but the formulas have been correctly identified in the answer by Hagen von Eitzen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation would be 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}t_a\\t_b\end{pmatrix}=  \begin{pmatrix}\cos X&\sin X\\-\sin X&\cos X\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$$
or $t_a=a\cos X+b\sin X$, $t_b=b\cos X-a\sin X$. Solving for $\sin X, \cos X$ gives the equations you have

Comment: I'm trying to solve those, my algebra is quite rusty though. Will accept the answer as soon as I get it (may take ages). Thank you.

Comment: OK done ! Thanks again.

Comment: There is something that I don't quite underrstand : the rotation matrix seems to downscale vectors that it rotates, why is it so ?